# Unable to delete %temp% files created due to Selenium Grid

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a grid configuration where the node is a windows 7 machine configured to run IE9 browser. Test Cases are running fine but after some time the browser gets slow. While searching I found out that it was due to the temp files created by the Selenium Grid `NODE`.

After clearing the Temp files created by the `NODE` the browser worked fine.

Now I need a way to clear the temp files on the `NODE` after a Test Case finishes execution or before starting a Test Case execution.

I tried to clear the system temp files from my Java code but this won't work in Grid configuration as the code runs in the HUB not `NODE`.

Is there any solution??

Comment: Try to connect to the remote machine and delete it  create full access to this folder and delete files  using your code FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);

Answer (score 0):

I've run into something very similar.

The system that I use, is a combination between selenium 1, and selenium 2 on a grid server on the intranet, which goes out to the AWS which is connected to several hundred nodes.

Each one of these nodes, once they start up the selenium server to run tests as a node, once that server is shut down, it will execute a batch file which just loops through each folder and deletes it in the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to execute a batch file that does the cleanup on the node machine.

Obtain the node address to use in the psexec command by making a POST call to the grid

```
http://<yourhub:port>/grid/api/testsession?session=" + driver.getSessionId()
```

The returned JSON will contain the session information, including the address of the node.

You can find sample code to get the node IP [here](http://selenium.polteq.com/en/get-remote-ip-address-of-node-selenium-grid/).